# javascript/jquery search in a subarray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

There is a string that is being formulated something like this
`Item:ShortName:Tax` and if more items are added, it is appended to string like `Item:ShortName:Tax_Item2:ShortName2:Tax2`, adding one more, `Item:ShortName:Tax_Item2:ShortName2:Tax2_Item3:ShortName3:Tax3` and so on. What I want to know is that, I have to check for if a item is present in the list, say, `shirt`, or `jeans`. It would be the first in array when separated by colon.

I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fgbmE/).

```
var list = "Item:ShortName:Tax_Item2:ShortName2:Tax2_Item3:ShortName3:Tax3_Item4:ShortName4:Tax4";

$(document).ready(function () {
    var arg = 'Item2';
    findItem(arg);
    fucntion findItem(argument) {
        $.each(list.split('_'), function () {
            if (this.split(':')[0] == arg) {
                alert('Item found!');
            }
        };
        };
```

But the alert doesn't appear, though `Item2` is in the list.
In case its not clear, this list split by `_` contains a array (as you can see) and each of that array separated by `:` contains `Itemname, ItemShortName, TaxOnItem`, now in all those small array, I have to check for first array that contains the `ItemName` to see if a particular item exists or not! How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some `{` and `(` as well as a typo. The console log tells you all this!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var list = "Item:ShortName:Tax_Item2:ShortName2:Tax2_Item3:ShortName3:Tax3_Item4:ShortName4:Tax4";
    var arg = 'Item2';
    findItem(arg);

    function findItem(argument) {
        $.each(list.split('_'), function () {
            if (this.split(':')[0] == arg) {
                alert('Item found!');
            }
        });
}

}​);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You do realise you got an error in your code, 
fucntion findItem(argument) { }
think you mean "function".

Answer (score 0):

Here: I slightly <strike>reformatted</strike> restructured your code. Try this:

```
var list = "Item:ShortName:Tax_Item2:ShortName2:Tax2_Item3:ShortName3:Tax3_Item4:ShortName4:Tax4";

function findItem(argument) {
    list.split("_").forEach(function(subList){
        if(subList.split(":")[0] == argument) { 
             alert("Item found!");
         }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    findItem("Item2");
};
```